# A Riddle In Between

Tags: riddle, word

**I'm looking for a 10-letter word.**

---

*Right now I'm twelfth.*

*But now I'm tenth.*

*Now I'm sixth.*

*It's weird I keep changing, now I am third.*

**What Am I?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the answer is

> APOSTROPHE

Each line refers to

> The character position of the apostrophe within the sentence (including spaces)

Comment: Also rot13(ncbfgebcurf bsgra nccrne orgjrra yrggref, nf vaqrrq gurl qb va gur dhrfgvba) (referring to the title!).